# Loading svg using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to inject SVG gradient definitions from external file using 'innerHTML' to keep my HTML clean.

It works fine in Chrome but not in Safari or Mobile Safari.
Any idea or workaround?

Here is a simplified example (the second gradient in injected, in the real word the html is requested from server):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="0" height="0">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x2="0" y2="1"> <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffff00"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#ff0000"/> </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <svg width="0" height="0" id="svg-grad"></svg>    
    <script>
      function inject_svg() {
        var gr2=document.getElementById('svg-grad');
        html='<defs><linearGradient id="grad2"><stop offset="0"  stop-color="#ffff00"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#ff0000"/> </linearGradient></defs>';
        gr2.innerHTML=html;
      }
    </script>    
    <svg width="200" height="200">
       <rect fill="url(#grad1)" x="20" y="20" width="50" height="150"/>
       <rect fill="url(#grad2)" x="100" y="20" width="50" height="150"/>
    </svg>
    <button onclick="inject_svg();">inject</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

In jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wPL4n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably adding things in the html namespace rather than the SVG namespace. Try using DOMParser instead and also setting an explicit namespace for the data (i.e. xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" on the root element of the data).

```
<svg width="0" height="0" id="svg-grad"></svg>

<script>
  function inject_svg() {
    var gr2=document.getElementById('svg-grad');
    html='<defs xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><linearGradient id="grad2"><stop offset="0"  stop-color="#ffff00"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#ff0000"/> </linearGradient></defs>';
    var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/xml");
    gr2.appendChild(xmlDoc.documentElement);
  }
</script>

<svg width="200" height="200">
   <rect fill="url(#grad1)" x="20" y="20" width="50" height="150"/>
   <rect fill="url(#grad2)" x="100" y="20" width="50" height="150"/>
</svg>
<button onclick="inject_svg();">inject</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, it works fine on Safari and mobile devices too.

Comment: reported the bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136903 just in case they could make it easier to use innerHTML.

Comment: it worked, but the problem is that with a def as the root element, the objects are not rendered (they are highlighted hovering over the inspector) so I replaced the root defs tag with a g and it works!

Answer (score 1):

### older webkit

You can use the [`innersvg.js polyfill`](https://code.google.com/p/innersvg/).

Based on webkit bug tracker: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136903, this problem is caused by different implementations of the DOM spec; specifically, `innerHTML/outerHTML` is defined on `HTMLElement` and `SVGElement` is not a subclass.

### webkit r176637+

2014-12-02 : This issue should be fixed :)

The patch [r176630](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/176630) changes that behavior and moves the definition up one level so they can be shared across `HTMLElement` and `SVGElement` and have a behavior closer to competing browsers/rendering engines.

If you live on the edge, you can get the [new nightly build](http://nightly.webkit.org/), e.g. [webkit r176637](http://builds.nightly.webkit.org/files/trunk/mac/WebKit-SVN-r176637.dmg) (note: I have not tried it out yet).